# ReactJS/TypeScript export object from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Ok, so I have multiple ajax calls (jQuery) that return, ofc, a list of items (an object for each function).

What I want here is so the component calls all those ajax gets, throws me the items and then I'm going to build another object with all those results (4 results will be merged into one object with different props).

My problem here is...how can I call & export those objects? I tried creating a big function and export it from TSX. Everything works, with a little bug...After going through those 4 ajax calls it keeps repeating like the component itself keeps refreshing and that gets me literally nowhere.

Any idea how I can export the results of the ajax call without seeing it LOOP like 100 times?

This is what I've tried so far ->

```
let CalendarItems = createCalendarItems();
export {CalendarItems};
```

P.S: I'm very new to React & diving into rather complex projects here so bear with me. Thanks in advance.

```
function getItems() {


  var today = new Date();
  return $.ajax({
    url: "SOMEURL"

    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
      var myitems = data.d.results;
      console.log("success  ");
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("Failed to get details ");
    }
  });
}
```

The purpose of this (perhaps it helps): ->

I'm making AJAX calls to Sharepoint to retrieve items (been there, done that, calls work). Those calls retrieve the list of items (4 lists) which I am joining in a new object.

This new object WILL be used as a list for react-bootstrap-table as in -> I will use this object to create my table.

So I will eventually pass the created object to this ->

```
  <BootstrapTable data={ calendarObjectAllItems} version='4'>
```

Comment: you said you're doing ajax calls, so does createCalendarItems return a promise?

Comment: probably going to need to see more than two lines of code to be able to tell what's going on...

Comment: If English (or other natural languages) were unambiguous we would write code in them directly. Since they aren't, we have developed programming languages to communicate with each other unambiguously. So rather than an English description of your problem, please post it in code.

Comment: There's literally not much code that i've wrote, i'm still trying to find out how i can export my object from one file to another (so to speak) lol. I've updated my question, perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to give specifics since you didn't provide much code. But generally speaking, if you need to load async stuff in a component, you'll kick that off using the componentDidMount lifecycle hook. So your component might look something like this:

```
import { fetchCalendarItems } from 'somewhere';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchCalendarItems()
      .then(items => this.setState({ items }))
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    // If necessary, you can render some placeholder until the data is loaded
    //if (items.length === 0) {
    //  return <div>Loading...</div>
    //}

    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(item => <div>{item.title}</div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So the component will mount and render empty (or render a loading screen if necessary). Then the http request is made, and when the request is complete it calls setState. This causes it to render again, now with the data.

Comment: I think i overstepped my boundaries trying to start with something so complex, any idea why "const {items}" shows as -> Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' has no property 'items' and no string index signature.

I don't want to make the component be called with those items (as in add them to react.component<>). 
If i still didnt annoy you enough please take a look at my initial question, i've updated it a bit perhaps you can narrow it down.

Comment: Those errors are coming from typescript. It looks like you didn't define the type for the component's state and/or props. Typically you'll do this by saying `class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State>`, where Props is a type definition for your props, and State is a type definition for your state. See the "how do you create a react component with typescript" section of this page: https://gist.github.com/juhaelee/b80ab497f74e7393b15439c17421d299

Comment: Hmm i do remember creating some components without needing all the props & state (since i didnt use them), perhaps i was wrong. Back to school for me, thanks!